# Optimize the rendering of React-Table with over 50 columns?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I've been using **React-Table** with over **50 columns** and `initialState.hiddenColumns` to show/hide the columns as per user-need, but rendering the whole table again & again according to this condition is quite slow. I've read out the documentation and some blogs, but couldn't find how to smooth-fix and fast the rendering of the whole table. 
Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A code of how you use ReactTable would help in providing suggestions

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm using ReactTable with useTable hook, as provided in the documentation. Any particular piece of code that you may require, as I've more than 50 columns, it won't be possible to paste all? This many columns with data slowing down the render. Thanks!